# I can not change my settings

Tags: system-settings

I deleted some files, `.conf` and others according to one of the comments to solve a problem.

After doing this, I cannot change any settings. Not even my wallpaper or my quick apps in launcher, and I cannot even update my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Any help?

Comment: What files? What comments? What problem? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: i am sorry i did not remember it  has been a while.
,but if you know anything the could help, i would be glad.
I think i may upgrade or downgrade will solve the problem, but i still can not know how to do that

Comment: We can't help unless you can tell us what you actually did. As a workaround, try creating a new user and logging in as them. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

looks like permission problems, try to run `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER`.

Comment: 1) That will only affect shell settings, not wallpaper or quick apps; 2) This will only fix any changes made in `.profile`, it will not help if any changes have been made in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc. In any case, none of bash's initialization files should be relevant here.

Comment: @terdon, your right, changed the answer...